# Error while trying to create Java Class out of .xsd file

Tags: java, xsd

I have two XMLs and i want convert them into java classes so i went to [this](http://www.xmlforasp.net/CodeBank/System_Xml_Schema/BuildSchema/BuildXMLSchema.aspx) page where i can generate .xsd files. I'm trying to make two Java Class out of them in Eclipse and I'm getting the same error:

```
parsing a schema...
[ERROR] Content is not allowed in prolog.
  line 1 of file:/(...)/queryClass.xsd

Failed to parse a schema.
```

These are my .xsd files:

First:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="dao" type="daoType" />
  <xsd:complexType name="daoType">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="query" type="queryType" />
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="queryType">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="arguments" type="argumentsType" />
      <xsd:element name="statement" type="xsd:string" />
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" />
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="argumentsType">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="argument" type="argumentType" />
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="argumentType">
    <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" />
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Second:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="properties" type="propertiesType" />
  <xsd:complexType name="propertiesType">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="entry" type="entryType" />
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="version" type="xsd:decimal" />
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="entryType">
    <xsd:attribute name="key" type="xsd:string" />
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: Maybe in your xsd-Files are invisible characters at the beginning of the file. Try to open them in hex-mode or in a Hex-Editor where you can see what really is written there.

Comment: Nope. That didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the XSD files were wrong. I used [another XML-XSD converter](https://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html) and it worked perfectly fine.